# I can't find a way to make this symbol appear visually fitting into the background

Tags: gimp, borders

I am designing a game card template and somewhat got forward pretty well. But now I am stuck on a detail with a symbol/relief in the middle of the design. This symbol is overlapping the bottom part and the top part.

[image]

On the bottom part I managed to cast a drop shadow that looks "ok" for me (image reference 3.). However the top part of that circle looks weird (image reference 1.) and does not fit with the black outlines I did with he other parts (image reference 2.). It tried to apply this outline to the symbol/relief as well but it always looks weird and very pixelated in comparison to the rectangle border lines.

Any suggestions how I can make this appear composed with the other style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you have already seen a shadow is helpful. Shadow needs light and you can make that light illuminate the upper edge (1) to make its effect symmetric.

[image]

Sorry, this screenshot is from Photoshop, but it doesn't change the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try to represent light phenomenon, known as ambient occlusion, more accurately. Also you should define bevels on edges. This is part of your card recreated with Inkscape.

[image: ambient occlusion on door]

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion: It doesn't need **anything**, including that "canned" drop shadow. The brown is of high enough contrast that it separates fine.

If you *must* include something,  use the thin dark brown rule you have around the rest of that mid-brown color.

[image]